# I installed cv2,when i run the code using cascade classifier class it is showing that module 'cv2' has no attribute 'CascadeClassifier'

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, face-detection

I installed `opencv` and i run the code for face detection using the class `CascadeClassifier`, but getting the error:

```
AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'CascadeClassifier'
```

Code:

```
import cv2

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_eye.xml')
```

please assist

Comment: What version of OpenCV did you installed? You can check it with `cv2.__version__`

Comment: I installed version2

Comment: 2.0? opencv.org has documentation starting from version 2.3 so I can't confirm if version 2.0 included CascadeClassifier